# How does cloud server company(such as aws, digital ocean... etc) provides many ips?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, digital-ocean, paas

nowdays I'm studying network layer and ips.

As I know, there are limited number of ips addresses.

However, cloud server company like aws and digital ocean can make many virtual instances and each instance can have unique ip or address.

For example in digital ocean, We can make many droplets and each of them have their own ip address.

How does it possible in limited number of ips:)?

I know the concept of VPN and NAT but... I cannot find clear answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They simply have bought a large batch of IP addresses beforehand from another provider.

They keep this pool at their own use and when a new instance is started they assign an IP from their pool to the instance.

When the machine is terminated, the IP address is returned to the pool, available for another customer.

Comment: Oh so they bought all those ips and sharing them.. thanks a lot :)